# Text does not go to next page, text hidden

Tags: page-breaking

When running the file below, there are a few problems:

- The section "employment history" automatically starts on the 2nd page, instead of the 1st page.
- The section "employment history" which starts on the 2nd page, does not jump to the 3rd page, instead the text written stays on the 2nd page and dissappears down.

How would I get the employment history section to start on the 1st page, and if I have written alot, it automatically continues to the 2nd page, and subsequentially 3rd, 4th, 5th page etc. ?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{array, xcolor, lipsum, bibentry}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{scrbase,scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings} % pagestyle with page number
\lohead{My Name}



\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.8}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedleft}p{0.14\textwidth}}
\newcolumntype{R}{p{0.8\textwidth}}
\newcommand\VRule{\color{lightgray}\vrule width 0.5pt}


\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\vspace*{-2cm}
\begin{center}\Huge My Name \end{center}
\vspace{1em}
\begin{minipage}[ht]{0.70\textwidth}
Address\\
Address\\
Address\\
Address\\
Address
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[ht]{0.48\textwidth}
contact\\
contact\\
contact\\
contact
\end{minipage}
\vspace{2pt}

\enlargethispage{3\baselineskip}


\section*{Employment History}
\begin{tabular}{L!{\VRule}R}
03/2011--Present&{\bf Insert Text.Insert Text.Insert Text.Insert Text.} Insert Text.Insert Text.Insert Text.Insert Text.Insert Text.Insert Text.Insert Text.Insert Text.Insert Text.Insert Text.Insert Text.Insert Text.Insert Text.Insert Text.Insert Text.Insert Text.Insert Text.Insert Text.Insert Text.Insert Text.Insert Text.Insert Text.Insert Text.Insert Text.Insert Text.Insert Text.Insert Text.Insert Text.Insert Text.Insert Text.Insert Text.Insert Text.\\
&\begin{itemize}
\item Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.
\item Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.
\item Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.
\item Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.
\end{itemize}\\
&In addition to my duties listed above, I have also: \\
&\begin{itemize}
\item Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.
\item Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.
\end{itemize}\\
07/2005--08/2007&{\bf Job Name} Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.\\
&\begin{itemize}
\item Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.
\item Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.
\item Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.
\end{itemize}\\
\end{tabular}



\end{document}
```

Comment: `tabular` environments are constructed in a block that does not break. As such, if it doesn't fit, it is pushed to a subsequent page. If it's too large for the subsequent page, it literally just overruns that page. Best here is to avoid the `tabular` construction, and set the entire content of that section in a list environment. Sure you can use a `longtable` (which breaks at the page boundary), but I don't think it's necessary/warranted in this case.

Comment: Thanks @Werner , do you have an example using a list environment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `longtable` instead of unbreakable `tabular` should solve the problem.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{array, xcolor, lipsum, bibentry}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{scrbase,scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings} % pagestyle with page number

\usepackage{longtable} % PS
\lohead{My Name}



\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.8}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedleft}p{0.14\textwidth}}
\newcolumntype{R}{p{0.8\textwidth}}
\newcommand\VRule{\color{lightgray}\vrule width 0.5pt}


\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\vspace*{-2cm}
\begin{center}\Huge My Name \end{center}
\vspace{1em}
\begin{minipage}[ht]{0.70\textwidth}
Address\\
Address\\
Address\\
Address\\
Address
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[ht]{0.48\textwidth}
contact\\
contact\\
contact\\
contact
\end{minipage}
\vspace{2pt}

\enlargethispage{3\baselineskip}


\section*{Employment History}
%\begin{tabular}{L!{\VRule}R}
\begin{longtable}{L!{\VRule}R}
03/2011--Present&{\bf Insert Text.Insert Text.Insert Text.Insert Text.} Insert Text.Insert Text.Insert Text.Insert Text.Insert Text.Insert Text.Insert Text.Insert Text.Insert Text.Insert Text.Insert Text.Insert Text.Insert Text.Insert Text.Insert Text.Insert Text.Insert Text.Insert Text.Insert Text.Insert Text.Insert Text.Insert Text.Insert Text.Insert Text.Insert Text.Insert Text.Insert Text.Insert Text.Insert Text.Insert Text.Insert Text.Insert Text.\\
&\begin{itemize}
\item Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.
\item Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.
\item Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.
\item Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.
\end{itemize}\\
&In addition to my duties listed above, I have also: \\
&\begin{itemize}
\item Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.
\item Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.
\end{itemize}\\
07/2005--08/2007&{\bf Job Name} Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.\\
&\begin{itemize}
\item Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.
\item Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.
\item Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.Job details.
\end{itemize}\\
%\end{tabular}
\end{longtable}



\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is a list-like approach for your resume. Lists can break across the page boundary, so there's no worry about subsequent overflows. I've added the `showframe` option to [`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) to highlight the page boundaries:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem,fancyhdr,lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{enumitem,fancyhdr,lipsum}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry
\fancyhead[L]{My Name}% Left header
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}% Right header
\fancyfoot{}% No footer
\pagestyle{fancy}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% Remove paragraph indent
\setlist[itemize,2]{label=\textbullet}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\vspace*{-2cm}
\begin{center}\Huge My Name \end{center}

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l}
  Address 1 \\ Address 2 \\ Address 3 \\ Address 4 \\ Address 5
\end{tabular}\hfill%
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}p{0.4\linewidth}}
  Contact 1 \\ Contact 2 \\ Contact 3 \\ Contact 4
\end{tabular}%

\bigskip

\section*{Employment History}

\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=9em]
  \item[03/2011--Present]
    \textbf{Insert Text.Insert Text.Insert Text.Insert Text.}
    \lipsum[1]

    \begin{itemize}
      \item \lipsum[2]

      \item \lipsum[3]

      \item \lipsum[4]

      \item \lipsum[5]
    \end{itemize}

    In addition to my duties listed above, I have also:

    \begin{itemize}
      \item \lipsum[6]

      \item \lipsum[7]
    \end{itemize}

    \item[07/2005--08/2007]
    \textbf{Job Name}
    \lipsum[8]

    \begin{itemize}
      \item \lipsum[9]

      \item \lipsum[10]

      \item \lipsum[11]
    \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```